# Transponer un datatable en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente Datatable que viene de una base de datos, estoy usando webforms

[image: Costos por vehículo]

Como puedo hacer para transponerla mediante C# y quede de la siguiente manera

[image: tabla transpuesta]

Trate de usar al siguiente rutina:

```
          dt2.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());

            foreach (DataRow inRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
                dt2.Columns.Add(newColName);
            }


            for (int rCount = 1; rCount <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; rCount++)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt2.NewRow();

                newRow[0] = dt.Columns[rCount].ColumnName.ToString().ToUpper();
                for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; cCount++)
                {
                    string colValue = dt.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
                    newRow[cCount + 1] = colValue;
                }
                dt2.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
```

Pero al encontrar un valor repetido da error obviamente porque la columna ya existe

Comment: Faltan detalles. Cómo construyes la tabla? Qué tecnología usas? MVC, WebForms, Winforms? Estás usando DevExpress? Boostrap Tables? Jquery DataTables? Y lo más importante... **Qué has intentado?**

Comment: eso no fue lo que te preguntaron diego... el datatable es un objeto que se usa para guardar el resultado de una consulta, que en general es a una base de datos. Vos haces la consulta a la base de datos? porque no transpones la consulta?